# creating multiple generators inside a list comprehension

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension

I am trying to group cards of the same suit (color) and rank inside generators and store those generators inside a list comprehension.

The solution I came up with does that except for the fact that all the generators contain exactly the same cards.  Any idea why?

Here is the code

```
deck=range(52)

gens=[(i for i in deck if i%13==v) for v in range(13)]
```

Based on this I would expect for example:

```
gens[1].next()
1
gens[1].next()
14


gens[10].next()
10
gens[10].next()
23
```

But instead I get

```
gens[1].next()
12

gens[1].next()
25

gens[1].next()
38
```

And all the generators in the list return the same results..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the name `v` in your generator expression refers to that variable `v` in the list comprehension. So, when the code your generator expression actually runs (when you call `next`), it looks at the variable `v` and sees the value `12`, no matter what the value of `v` was when you created the generator.

One workaround:

```
deck = range(52)

def select_kth(v):
    return (i for i in deck if i % 13 == v)

gens = [select_kth(v) for v in range(13)]
```

Because we defined a function, the name `v` gets to live in its own naming environment and so stays around unmodified.

If you really wanted, you could do this in one line:

```
 gens = [(lambda v: (i for i in deck if i % 13 == v))(v) for v in range(13)]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you turn this into the equivalent nested loops, you can see the scoping problem more easily:

```
gens = []
for v in range(13):
    def gen():
        for i in deck:
            if i%13 == v:
                yield i
    gens.append(gen())
```

You end up with 13 generators all bound to the same value of `v`, 12.

So, the solution here is the same as in any other scoping problem: you need to create a new scope with the `v` in it. The easiest way to do this is to create a new function:

```
gens = [(lambda x: (i for i in deck if i%13==x)(v) for v in range(13)]
```

Comment: I was going to delete this, because it's really the same answer as Dougal's, and he got here a minute before me, but… it's got some upvotes, so I guess people think it's worth keeping around anyway… Or maybe Dougal should just copy the conversion to nested loops and have the best of both worlds in one answer?

Comment: Your answer is a totally different way of explaining this. I would leave it.

Comment: I like your explanation and think it's worth keeping on its own rather than me stealing it, no need to delete. :)